# Cannot Change Permissions for Plist file in Mojave

Tags: mojave, permission

I'm using Mojave and I'm trying to change the permissions for this file

/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Slideshows.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Content/EffectDescriptions.plist

I want to alter the duration that slides appear in my screensaver which I've figured out how to do but I cannot save my edits to the file.  I continually get the error Operation not permitted.  I have tried editing the file on the desktop that moving the file back but that does not work.  That operation is denied.  I cannot change permissions through getinfo and I cannot change permissions through the terminal command:

sudo chown myname /System/Library/

And also

sudo chown myname /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Slideshows.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Content/EffectDescriptions.plist

This article seems to deal with the problem but I really cannot tell what the guy is saying:

https://eclecticlight.co/2020/03/04/how-macos-10-14-and-later-overrides-write-permission-on-some-files/

Answer (score 0):

I had to turn off the system integrity protection available.  The steps for doing that are here

https://www.imore.com/how-turn-system-integrity-protection-macos

After that I could change the permissions for plist file using getinfo and make the changes I wanted.